# Is there a method func for functions to get information of a function?

Tags: go, types, metaprogramming, custom-data-type

//as we can return a function in go

//as we can pass function as a parameter in go

Here is what I mean by information of a function:

- list of returned (data/function) types
- list of its arguments (data/function) types with values

My general Goal is to get rid of very small **( super small near zero )** probabilities of some random values returned by function results.

The problem is that there **( super small near zero )** probability of duplicate results. it gets greater as the length of the result wanted gets smaller, and greater if generate more random values. **( are countless in my case )**

here is an example :

```
func RandomPassword(min, max int) string {
    ...
    return password
}

func RandomEmail() string {
    return RandomStr(6) + "@" + RandomStr(6) + ".com" 
    // 6 is length of the returned string
}

func RandomName() string {
    return RandomStr(12)
}
```

so I implemented a function to check whether two results are equal or not. he is my approach, but **I don't know how** to get information of a method using the **reflect package, (which is my question)**

```
//r is my random value
//f is a function that returns a random value

func RandomMustDiff(r any, f func(...any)) {

    // if return(data/function)types == reflect.TypeOf(r) {
    panic("types aren't equal")
    }

    // get the function arguments
    args := f.args()
    

    // check-results code
    if r != f(args) {
        return RandomMustDiff(r, f(args))
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need reflection for this, you just need to store the result of the function in a `map[string]bool`. When you call the function again, you can check if the result is already in the map. If so, it's a duplicate, if not, it isn't.

Comment: storing a value in a map is trivial only if I knew the data type. since not all the struct I want to pass to MustDiff function are known respectively to it's random generator function. let's say I have a function that returns a random Person struct. How would I check in  "returned.type() == reflect.TypeOf(r)"  the equality of types. It's not a duplicate question.